# ionic 3 inapp browser camera access for chatting

Tags: android, ios, camera, ionic3, inappbrowser

Hi i want to show a website as mobile application using inappbrowser in ionic 3, in that application there is a videochat screen where the camera needs to be accessed, while i am clicking on that it i show error message(in mobile browser it is working fine), i have added camera access is Androidmainfest.xml and allow camera permission in the app startup, still facing the error, please help me out

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN7lb.png)

in app.module.ts

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
```

in app.component.ts

```
 androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
            [
              androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA,
              androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
              androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
               androidPermissions.PERMISSION.MICROPHONE,
               androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
               androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
              ]
          );
```

in Androidmainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.resource.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?